# Custom field type:problem in page layout

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a custom field type and its working properly but when I am adding it on page layout ,its not displaying any data in there.I am getting data from one of the list.I have added my custom field in list and its displaying all the data I have specified but on page layout its blank.....
Any idea where i m getting wrong...?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [PublishingAssociatedContentType](http://www.katriendg.com/aboutdotnet/2007-6-moss-2007-publishing-page-layout.aspx) of the Page Layout to a Content Type that contains the custom Field. You can do this through the provisioning XML or in the browser by editing the Page Layout properties in the Master Page Gallery.